# WCF Saving EF 4.1 item throws exception An item cannot be added to a fixed size Array of type

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4, dbcontext, savechanges

I have searched google and exhausted a fair bit of my time trying to figure out what is going on with my WCF and client Windows form app.

I am continuously getting the following error

```
"Unable to set field/property Ingredients on entity type Datalayer.UnitOfMeasure. See InnerException for details."
...
inner exception is 
"An item cannot be added to a fixed size Array of type 'Datalayer.Ingredient[]'."


Stack Trace - 
    at System.Data.Objects.Internal.PocoPropertyAccessorStrategy.<AddToCollection>b__0[T](Object collectionArg, Object item)
       at System.Data.Objects.Internal.PocoPropertyAccessorStrategy.CollectionAdd(RelatedEnd relatedEnd, Object value)
```

The way I have configured my solutions I have a WCF web-service which reference my DataLayer class library, I have a windows app (test app) which references the WCF services as well as DataLayer project.

If I don't reference the DataLayer in my test app, this issues does not occur however I lose the `ICollection<Ingredient>` to simple `Ingredient[]` array. Now as you can see this becomes a coding pain to initialize the array every time.

Any idea anyone? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding reference to WCF service in the test using 'Add Service Reference' there is a option to configure the default collection type for the generate proxy on the client. The default i think is array, you can change it to a generic list.

In case you are using svcutil,that too allows the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

I was running into this exact error, but the accepted answer wasn't quite the solution I needed. It turns out that the client was sending a `List<Order>` up to my WCF service, but since the `Customer.Orders` property was defined as an `ICollection<Order>`, the WCF deserializer deserializer just deserialized it in the simplest form it could, which was an array of type Order, i.e., `Order[]`.

The only solution I was able to come up with was to change the property in question on my POCO objects from an `ICollection<Order>` to a `HashSet<Order>`. See [Stop WCF Deserializing Empty ICollection into Zero Capacity Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244910/stop-wcf-deserializing-empty-icollection-into-zero-capacity-array/10846943) for a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I had this same error, and was doing the right thing, calling "ToArray()". Changed it to "ToList()" and it started working fine.

Comment: Pfffff.... I ended up here after googling this error. Found this answer and it worked a treat. Went to vote it up as the correct answer, only to realise it was posted by me two years ago! I suspect I ended up here then googling the same error in the same project.