# Stop WCF Deserializing Empty ICollection into Zero Capacity Array

Tags: wcf, serialization, entity-framework-4.1

I'm having a problem using WCF and Entity Framework 4.1 POCO objects (generated using T4 templates). My basic problem is that when sending a POCO object from my client to the service, WCF is deserializing a member variable of type ICollection as a fixed size array.

On the client side I can tell visual studio to use IList instead of T[] - but I cant see any option like this on the server end.

This causes no end of problems with several things, such as persisting these objects back to the database.

Is there any way to tell WCF what object type to deserialize ICollection (or any array) as?

Comment: If your member variable is of type `ICollection` causes `no end of problems` then why have you defined it as something that cannot be handled? ie why not define it as `IList` if thats what your persister expects. Perhaps elaborate on what issues that causes downstream

Comment: Because the POCO T4 templates specify ICollection - I'm not writing the POCO's by hand. As an interim measure I have amended the T4 templates to create HashSet instead which works fine, but it seems to me that their ought to be a way to specify what concrete type to use when deserializing a specified generic / interface type.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised that more folks haven't run into this issue, as it hits you smack in the face when you try to use the EF T4-generated POCO objects over WCF. Specifically, the error I was getting said something like:

> Exception: "Unable to set field/property Orders on entity type Datalayer.Customers. See InnerException for details."
>
> InnerException: "An item cannot be added to a fixed size Array of type 'Datalayer.Order[]'."

At any rate, the only solution I've been able to come up with is the one that you mention, namely, modifying the T4 templates to use HashSet instead of ICollection. Doesn't strike me as the cleanest, but it seems to work.

Comment: Interrestingly, I have the same problem in the opposite direction (Server to Client). This is way more problematic as the client could not add or remove rows to a fixed size array. I've tried Modifying the T4 template to replace ICollection with HashSet. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: That sounds like it may be an issue with the parameters you specify in the "Add Service Reference" dialog box (or svcutil.exe). Have you tried specifying the collection type to be used as ObservableCollection?

Comment: Solved it using System.Collection.Generic.List instead of System.Array as selected collection type in the "Add Service Reference" dialog.

Comment: @omatrot - That works if you're adding the items to the list from the client side. But if the server has received a list from the client and needs to add an item to it before saving it to the database, you'll still hit the error. And at that point, you need to muck about with the T4 templates. (At least, I couldn't figure out any other way to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Entity Framework 6, and I was able to solve this issue by making the following changes in my T4 template.

I changed the following line where it creates the navigation properties to use a List instead of a collection from

```
navProp.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
```

to

```
navProp.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("List<" + endType + ">") : endType,
```

Then I changed the code that sets the navigation property in the constructor to convert the default hashset to a list by adding a call to .ToList(). This line

```
this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty)#> = new HashSet<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>();
```

was changed to

```
this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty)#> = new HashSet<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>().ToList();
```

The HashSet<>.ToList() method is an extension, so in order to make that extension method available, I added a using System.Linq statement by modifying the UsingDirectives method:

```
    public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
{
    return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
        ? string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}using System;{1}" + Environment.NewLine +
            "{0}using System.Linq;" + 
            "{2}",
            inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
            includeCollections ? (Environment.NewLine + "using System.Collections.Generic;") : "",
            inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine,
            Environment.NewLine)
        : "";
}
```