# C# EF6 entity mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am currently working on a project (WCF Service) that should utilize EF6 with a MySql database. That part itself is already working as it should, but I am having huge problems with the mapping.

I have 3 entities like following:

```
Employee - ManyToMany - Project - OneToMany - ProjectStep
```

My database model is set up like this:

Employee table:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Department` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DirectDialing` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

Project table:

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Titel` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectLeader` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `project_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectLeader`) REFERENCES `employee` (`ID`)
)
```

ProjectStep table:

```
CREATE TABLE `project_step` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` text,
  `StartDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Project` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `project_step_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Project`) REFERENCES `project` (`ID`)
)
```

Mapping table Employee - Project

```
CREATE TABLE `employee_project` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EmployeeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `projectId_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectId`) REFERENCES `project` (`ID`)
  CONSTRAINT `employeeId_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeId`) REFERENCES `employee` (`ID`)
)
```

I then created my entities as following:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "Shared")]
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Projects = new List<Project>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Berufsbezeichnung { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Abteilung { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Durchwahl { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "Shared")]
public class Project
{

    public Project()
    {
        this.EmployeesWorkingOnProject = new List<Employee>();
        this.ProjectSteps = new List<ProjectStep>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Titel { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartDatum { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime EndDatum { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Beschreibung { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column("Projektleiter")]
    public Employee Projektleiter { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeesWorkingOnProject { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("Project")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectStep> ProjectSteps { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "Shared")]
public class ProjectStep
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Beschreibung { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartDatum { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime EndDatum { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

and used `Fluent API` to create the `ManyToMany` relationship as well as the `OneToMany`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasMany(e => e.Projects).WithMany(t => t.EmployeesWorkingOnProject).Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("MitarbeiterID");
        m.MapRightKey("ProjektID");
        m.ToTable("mitarbeiter_projekte");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectStep>().HasRequired<Project>(p => p.Project).WithMany(p => p.ProjectSteps);
}
```

I am really at a loss, because when I am trying to insert a new `Project`, I get the error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ProjectSteps' on type
>   'Shared.Project' is not valid. The foreign key name 'Project' was not
>   found on the dependent type 'Shared.ProjectStep'. The Name value
>   should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

I think that I have a few problems in my mapping which are the reason for this error. I am completely at a loss as to where my mapping is wrong as well as if I even used the right way.

So my question is, should one even mix the `DataAnnotations` with `Fluent API`, and could someone help me getting this mapping right?

Please note, that this is my very first C#/EF6 project and that I am not very common with everything so some explanation is welcome.

Comment: I think you need to use an `Id` field as your foreign key, such as `ProjectId`. A collection can't be a key, can it? I'm only slightly more familiar than you, but it seems you shouldn't do some with Fluent and some with DataAnnotations and some via data first. You can set your constraints in any of those three ways, so why not do them all in one?

Comment: @Tim for some reason `data first` doesn't work in my VS. `DataAnnotations`would require one more entity for the `ManyToMany` mapping right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data annotations and fluent configurations can be mixed. But especially for relationships I find fluent configuration much more intuitive. The problem with `ForeignKey` attribute is that it could be applied to the FK property, in which case it is used to specify the navigation property name. Or it could be applied to the navigation property, in which case it should contain the FK *property* name (or comma separated list of composite FK property names).

The important thing to know is that it *cannot* be used to specify the FK *column* name. The column names are controlled by the `Column` attribute, hence it can be used only if you have explicit FK property (which you don't).

Fluent API has no such limitations. You either use `HasForeignKey` when you have explicit FK property, or `Map` with `MapKey` when you don't.

In your case, in order to specify your unusual "Project" as FK column name, you can use the following fluent configuration (and don't forget to remove the invalid `ForeignKey` attribute from `ProjectSteps`):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectStep>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.Project)
    .WithMany(s => s.ProjectSteps)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("Project"));
```

Comment: I have multiple problems with `fixed size Arrays`. Do you have any idea what could cause them?

Comment: Fixed size arrays? I don't think EF supports such thing. But you can post another question showing exactly the problematic case.

Comment: I mean that is the error I get on my lists: `InvalidOperationException: An item cannot be added to a fixed size Array of type 'Shared.ProjectStep[]'.`

Comment: I see. Can't tell without seeing the usage case, but most likely is something related to WCF serialization. `ICollection<ProjectStep>` allows assigning `ProjectStep[]`. If it's not by your own code, should be by WCF I guess. Just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244910/stop-wcf-deserializing-empty-icollection-into-zero-capacity-array. Looks like the workaround is to use `List<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>` for navigation property types.

Comment: Already tried that one, but didn't work. Will make a new question towards that issue

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to add new "Project" to db, you'll need to remove foreign key annotation from "ProjectSteps" property in "Project" class. "Foreign Key" annotation can be applied only to properties which are not collection type.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "Shared")]
public class Project
{

    public Project()
    {
        this.EmployeesWorkingOnProject = new List<Employee>();
        this.ProjectSteps = new List<ProjectStep>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Titel { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartDatum { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime EndDatum { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Beschreibung { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column("Projektleiter")]
    public Employee Projektleiter { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeesWorkingOnProject { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectStep> ProjectSteps { get; set; }
}
```

In addtition answering you question:

> So my question is, should one even mix the DataAnnotations with Fluent API, and could someone help me getting this mapping right?

Mixing is not a good practice. Imho Fluent API is always better, because it gives much more mapping options.

For more info about EF mappings, check out [THIS](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx)