# Entity Framework 5 error when adding (EntityException)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

```
 public Person Cadastrar(Person pPerson, PersonData pPersonData)
        {
            Entidade ent = new Entidade();
            pPersonData.Person = pPerson;
            ent.Person.Add(pPerson); // if i save changes here, works.
        ent.PersonData.add(pPersonData); //Getting EntityException.
            ent.SaveChanges();
            return ent.Person.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

PersonData deppends of a PK on Person. Why am I getting EntityException? pPersonData is the same tipe as PersonData, plus if i remove that line i do create a register on my Person table.

Comment: What exception are you getting? (we need more details than entityexception)

Comment: {"Unable to set field/property PersonData on entity type ServicoIdentificacao.Person. See InnerException for details."}

InnerException:
{"An item cannot be added to a fixed size Array of type 'ServicoIdentificacao.PersonData[]'."}

Comment: Can you please also post your ServicoIdentificacao entity?

Comment: public DbSet<UserData> UserData { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Persondata> PersonData { get; set; }

Comment: How can you ask a question and leave out all this vital information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Saving EF 4.1 item throws exception An item cannot be added to a fixed size Array of type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055094/wcf-saving-ef-4-1-item-throws-exception-an-item-cannot-be-added-to-a-fixed-size)